# A Different Proof of the Global Frobenius Theorem?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

The two proofs of the theorem I have seen rely on the construction of a certain manifold, which entails defining a topology, constructing charts, and checking the required conditions. For example, this is the approach in Lee's extremely readable "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds". I want to find proof that avoids the construction. I think the following sketch is ok, except maybe for step $3).$ I'd like some feedback in general, and in particular, on step $3)$:

If $D\subseteq TM$ is an $l-$ dimensional involutive distribution on an $n-$ dimensional manifold $M,$

$1).\ $ There is a countable collection of charts $(U_i,\phi_i)$ such that the $\{U_i\}$ cover $M$ and for each $U_i,$ the slice : $$S_i(c)=\{x\in U_i:\phi_i^{l+1}(x)=c^{l+1},\cdots ,\phi_i^n(x)=c^n\}\space \text{is an integral manifold of} \space D.$$

$2).\ $ Let $\mathscr S$ be the collection of all the $S_i(c)$ as $c$ ranges over $\mathbb R^{n-l-1}$ and for all charts $(U_i,\phi_i)$.

$3).\ $ This idea is taken from a step in Lee's proof. Define an equivalence relation on $\mathscr S$ by saying that two members $S_i(c_i),S_j(d_j)$ are equivalent if there is a finite sequence of slices from $S_i(c_i)$ to $S_j(d_j)$, defined by requiring that any two adjacent members have non-void intersection.

This forces $c_i=d_i=c$ for some fixed $c$. And since $\{U_i\}$ is at most countable, this means that the number of endpoints of sequences is at most countable. Fix two such endpoints and note that the number of paths between them is at most countable, since each $S_i$ is an integral manifold, and therefore it can intersect at most countably many slices in $U_{i+1}$. Hence, each equivalence class is at most countable.

$4).\ $ For a given equivalence class, which we may enumerate $\{A_1, A_2,\cdots\},$ define $\tilde A_j=\bigcup_{i=1}^jA_i,$ which are embedded manifolds (follows directly from the fact that each member of the union is an integral manifold of $D$).

Now set $A=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}\tilde A_j$. Show that $A$ is an immersion. This follows from the fact that the union is increaasing so if $x\in A$ then $x\in \tilde A_j$ for some integer $j$ and so if $i:A\to M$ and $i_j:A_j\to A$ are inclusions $i=i_j$ in a sufficiently small neighborhood of $x$.

$5).\ $ Show that the immersions in the previous step you get for each equivalence class form a foliation of $M$ and are maximal with respect to $D$. This works the same way as in Lee's proof on-page $505.$

Comment: Interesting idea. But there are a few things here that don't quite make sense. First, I don't understand your claim that "$c_i = d_i = c$ for some fixed $c$." It's certainly possible for two slices $S_i(c)$ and $S_i(c')$ to be equivalent even though $c\ne c'$. Second, and more importantly, what does it mean to say that "$A$ is an immersion"? $A$ is a subset of $M$, while an immersion is a kind of map from a smooth manifold into $M$. Maybe you mean to say that $A$ is an immersed submanifold of $M$; but for that to make sense, you have to define a topology and smooth structure on $A$.

Comment: @ Jack Lee: I thought that the way I defined $\sim,$ since at each step adjacent slices have to intersect, so $c_i=d_i=c.$ I was thinking of parallel lines and planes etc. For the second comment, yes I meant $A$ is an immersed manifold, giving $A$ the subspace topology. (I did not work out the details though). I guess there is no way then to get around the lemma in your book?  Thanks for taking the time to comment

Comment: I don't quite follow your argument that $c_i=d_i=c$; but it's certainly possible for two different slices in the same slice chart to be equivalent. See Figure 19.8 in my ISM for an idea how this can happen.

Comment: I don't know if it's true that "there's no way to get around the lemma in my book," but in any case, to show that $A$ is an immersed submanifold, you're going to have to decide how to define a topology and smooth structure on it.

Comment: @JackLee; Actually, what got me thinking about all this was exactly fig. 19.8, which I guess I do not understand. The first slice (shaded) intersects the second (shaded), going toward the right, then the second intersects an object that starts flat and curves downward and to the left. But this object is not a slice, Its intersection with $W_{i}$ is a slice, $S_{i}$ as is its intersection with $W_{i+1}$  the slice $S_{i+1}$ but $S_{i}\cap S_{i+1}=\emptyset.$ So, I am obviously missing something.

Comment: A few notes that might help clarify: The thing labeled $W_i$ is a flat chart. The shaded thing containing $p_0$ is one slice in that flat chart. The next shaded thing to the right is a slice in another flat chart. The curved shaded thing is a slice in a third flat chart. (The fact that it's curved doesn't matter, because it's diffeomorphic to a single slice in a coordinate cube.) Note that the third flat chart does not intersect $W_i$ at all.

Comment: So the curved thing is a slice just because there is by definition, a diffeo $\varphi$ that straightens it out, sending it to a "really flat thing" in $\mathbb R^n$. That's  the piece I was missing. Ugh. Now, doesn't it still hold that the number of equivalece classes in $3).$ is countable? Because if $S(c)\subset U_i$ is an endpoint say the first, then $S(c)$ can intersect only countable many other slices in $U_i$, no matter what $c$ is. As far as the union of the spaces in $4).$ being an immersed manifold, I think if we give it the topology coherent with the $\tilde A_j$ then it works (cont)

Comment: because if we define $f:A\to M$ by its restriction to the inclusions from $\tilde A_j$, then $f$ will be an immersion. But I guess we still have to show that the we can give $A$ the structure of a manifold with this topology, so we are back to your proof! Ugh again...

Comment: Yes, it sounds is if you're basically recreating my proof of Lemma 19.22.